# ASP.NET Windows authorization redirect users to custom page

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, windows-authentication

Is it possible to redirect users that are not authorized to a page displaying a message ?
I ahve following settings in config file. When users who don't have access to folder Admin try to access the pages in Folder Admin, the application pops up windows login form.
Instead I would like to redirect the users to AccessDenied.aspx page.

I am using Windows Authentication.

My web.config is as follows:

```
<!-- Admin Authorization -->
  <location path="Admin">
    <system.web>

      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin"/>

        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>

    </system.web>
  </location >
```